# google maps infoWindow button ( ionic ) issue

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

Im traryng to do something like this on ionic

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8ZsSp/)

But i have a issue when i add a infoWindows button , 
specifically in this section  `(click)="ir()"`  (angular)

```html
 ir(){
    console.log("go");
  }

      addMarker(position,map,title){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position,
          map,
          title
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:" "
        });
        


        marker.addListener('click',function(){
          infoWindow.setContent('<h1> '+ title +'</h1>' +
              '<button class="mapaboton" (click)="ir()">Ver Detalles</button>'); 
            infoWindow.open(map,this);
        });



      }
```

Sorry for my english

when i click on it nothing happens.
then i changed `(click)="ir()"` for `onclick="ir()"` and it throw me  the next error

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ir is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
marker.addListener('click',()=>{
          infoWindow.setContent('<h1> '+ title +'</h1>' +
              '<button class="mapaboton" (click)="ir()">Ver Detalles</button>'); 
            infoWindow.open(map,this);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NgZone for this:

```js
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public ngZone: NgZone) {}

(<any>window).ionicPageRef = {
    zone: this.ngZone,
    component: this
};

let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: <button onClick='window.ionicPageRef.zone.run(function () { window.ionicPageRef.component.MyFunction() })'>My button</button>"
});
```